# Scrape data from website understanding the parameters to send for the XHR request

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, get-request

I am new here.

I am beginning to learn how to **scrape** websites, but my knowledge in this field is really low.

I have a certain website on which I am testing my scraping abilities and, for now, I am able to make requests for what I need through QNetworkManager, which are similar to those I read on the Chrome console. The problem is that these requests contains three parameters which are obscure to me. One seems to be constant for now, so it bothers me little. The other two seems to be some datetime in seconds, with respect to epoch.

Here come the main problem: when I try to send requests with the GET method, and I change the parameters I know, the server does not reply in the expected way.

I know that somewhere my browser knows how to generate those parameters and my question is: is there a way to simply find where this happens and how? I tried reading the JS of the api, but it is really difficult to understand, it seems to be encrypted or something similar.

I am sorry if this question is too wide or confusing, I am really a newbie in this field :(

Thanks! :)

Comment: It depends a lot on the server in question; it may be requesting very specific parameters in order to return any data. I'd suggest testing GET requests against open sites like [**JSONPlaceholder**](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) to test your requests.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks for the link. I tested my requests and, as long as I copy the url from the Chrome console, they work. But if I change any parameter a few (let's say the parameter longitude, from 44.023 to 44.035) the server replies "Server overloaded", which is not good.

Comment: Please share some specific example.